# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript

```js
var login = document.getElementById('log-in');
var front = document.querySelector('.user-front');
var back = document.querySelector('.user-login');
var humburger = document.getElementById('navigation__humburger');



// hamburgerMenu
humburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (humburger.classList.contains('navigation__humburger_active')) {
       humburger.classList.remove('navigation__humburger_active');
    } else {
        humburger.classList.add('navigation__humburger_active');

    }
});

//Log-in
login.addEventListener('click',function () {
    front.style.cssText='transform: rotateY(180deg) translate(50%,-50%); \
    backface-visibility: hidden; \
    transition: 1s; ';
    back.style.cssText='transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  ';
    login.style.display = 'none';
});
```

[image: код]

у меня дву разные функции на события по клику, одна работает , другая нет но если поменять местами то наоборот вторая которая стала первой работает, а первая нет.
Обе эти функции написаны для разных страниц HTML., видимо в этом проблема. Интерпретатор спотыкается и cannot read property addeventlistener of null?
но как иначе сделать?не писать же для каждой страницы отдельный скрипт?

Comment: изящное решение обязательно есть, будет здорово если вы создадите [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), а также оформите код в виде текста, а не картинки

Answer (score 4):

Ответ очень простой, делайте проверку, перед тем, как добавлять слушатель на элемент.

Например перед строками, где вы добавляете слушатель, сделайте что-то в этом роде:

```
if(humburger){
   humburger.addEventListener....


}
```

И также для второго случая

Comment: Да, отлично, помогло!

Answer (score 0):

В html файле где подключаете  пропишите атрибут defer.

```
<script src="script.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: Не поможет. Это могло бы решить проблему, если бы скрипт шёл раньше нужного dom-элемента, а в вопросе ситуация, когда одного из двух элементов на странице вообще нет. Причём то, какого именно нет, зависит от страницы.